# How to create multiple graphs for Y = (Values in different columns for a given variable) and X = Time

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]In my dat2 file I have a series of body measurements for various subjects. These body measurements are bicep, tricep, suprailiac, sub scapular....ffm (fat free mass). I have taken these measurements at 0,6,12 weeks. The subjects were on either treatment 'a' or treatment 'b'.

I would like to create multiple graphs for both treatments where Y = Body Measurement and X = Time. I know how to do this for just one variable like "weight".

```
line <- ggplot(dat2, aes(time, weight))

line +  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point") + 
stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line", aes(group = 1)) + 
stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.2) +
facet_wrap(~ treatment, nrow = 4) + labs(x = "Time", y = "Weight") +
scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = c(0, 6, 12))
```

I tried the following code to do this for multiple variables and to print multiple graphs.

```
dat2 %>% select(code:solidfatstotallog, time, bicep, tricep, subscapular, suprailiac, weight, wc, bia, bmi, wthr, X.fat, fm, ffm,     height, density)

dat2 %>% 
select(code, treatment, time, bicep:ffm)
gather(body_measure, value, -c(code, treatment, time)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(time, body_measure)) +
stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point") + 
stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line", aes(group = 1)) + 
stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.2) +
facet_wrap(~ treatment, nrow = 4) + labs(x = "Time", y = "Body_Measure") +
scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = c(0, 6, 12))
```

However, this just creates one graph of Y = weight and X = Time. With different labels where Y is now body_measure. What am I missing here?

See example picture for Weight by Time. I would like to create multiple such graphs, ideally on a single page.

So I was able to create a facet_grid, but the graph is not nice to look at. I used the following code.

```
dat2 %>% 
select(code, treatment, time, bicep:ffm, -c(density, height)) %>% #drop irrelevant variables
gather(measure, score, -c(code, treatment, time)) %>% #data into long form 
ggplot(aes(time, score)) +
stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point") + 
stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line", aes(group = 1)) + 
stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.2) +
facet_grid(treatment ~ measure) + labs(x = "Time", y = "Body_Measure") +
scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = c(0, 6, 12))
```

[image: Facet_Grid]

Comment: @Gregor Thanks! Isn't gather() doing that in my code?

Comment: Ah, I suppose. Without seeing your data it's hard to track. I'm confused though--what don't you like about the facet grid? It's multiple graphs on a single page. Perhaps you should experiment with different faceting options, see `?facet_grid` for details. Things like `scales = "free_y", space = "free"` might help, or maybe using `measure ~ treatment` instead of the reverse... or maybe just adjusting the dimensions of the plot.